# Passing UTM Parameters using Javascript to Button URL

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here I have a code that is supposed to take the utm parameters in the url and pass it to all buttons who have a specific href domain. However this code runs a compile error on Line 12 Character 27 which is the line with the for-loop and I do not understand why. Can someone please help.
Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
var utmInheritingDomain = "https://www.motorstore.com/amr_en/checkout/", 
utmRegExp = /(\&|\?)utm_[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+/gi,
links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
utms = [
"utm_medium={{utm_medium}}", 
"utm_source={{utm_source}}", 
"utm_campaign={{utm_campaign}}", 
];

for (var index = 0; index 0) { 
tempLink = tempLink.replace(utmRegExp, "");

tempParts = tempLink.split("#");

if (tempParts[0].indexOf("?") < 0 ) {
tempParts[0] += "?" + utms.join("&"); 
} else {
tempParts[0] += "&" + utms.join("&");
}

tempLink = tempParts.join("#");
}

links[index].href = tempLink;
}
}());

</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to iterate over?

Comment: Exact compiler error is Error at line 12, character 27: Parse error. ';' expected

Comment: Yes I know, but I mean for what element is your `for` loop? "`for (var index = 0; index 0) { `" is invalid. What are you trying to loop?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a `}` too much and your for loop is invalid

```js
(function() {
    var utmInheritingDomain = "https://www.motorstore.com/amr_en/checkout/", 
    utmRegExp = /(\&|\?)utm_[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+/gi,
    links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    utms = [
        "utm_medium={{utm_medium}}", 
        "utm_source={{utm_source}}", 
        "utm_campaign={{utm_campaign}}", 
    ];

    // Invalid for loop
    // for (var index = 0; index 0) {
    for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index++ 
        tempLink = tempLink.replace(utmRegExp, "");

        tempParts = tempLink.split("#");

        if (tempParts[0].indexOf("?") < 0 ) {
            tempParts[0] += "?" + utms.join("&"); 
        } else {
            tempParts[0] += "&" + utms.join("&");
        }

        tempLink = tempParts.join("#");
    }

    links[index].href = tempLink;
    // } <- this one
}());
```

Also your `tempLink` and `tempParts` variables aren't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You want it to say something like

```
for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
```